# Hibernate with java ArrayList

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

i have try to use Hibernate with this class that include
`ArrayList` :

but i get this exception:

```
expected type: java.util.ArrayList, actual value: org.hibernate.collection.PersistentList
```

(i must use Arraylist because just List is't Serializable and it's make me trouble)

this exception throw when the jpa entitymanager start.

this is the class:

```
package Entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import msg.AnsMsg;


public class Person implements Serializable {

    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private long id;
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    private String _email;

    private ArrayList <AnsMsg> msgList=new ArrayList<AnsMsg>();



   public ArrayList <AnsMsg> getMsgList() {

       return msgList;
    }


    public void setMsgList(ArrayList <AnsMsg> msgList) {
        this.msgList = msgList;
    }






    public Person(){}


    public String getEmail() {
        return _email;
    }


    public void set_email(String _email) {
        this._email = _email;
    }
}
```

this is the hbm file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Apr 17, 2012 9:20:13 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Entities.Person" table="PERSON">
        <id name="id" type="long">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="_email" type="java.lang.String" access="field">
            <column name="_EMAIL" />
        </property>

        <list name="msgList" inverse="false" table="ANSMSG" lazy="true">
            <key>
                <column name="ID" />
            </key>
            <list-index></list-index>
            <one-to-many class="msg.AnsMsg" />
        </list>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

how can i use java Arraylist with hibernate, 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to associate the interface List and not the actual ArrayList class. If you see the PersistetList documentation http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/collection/PersistentList.html it implements java.util.List.

Comment: the problem is that i  move Person object from Server to my Android and when my android app try to DeSerialize Person object i get null object because this List instead using Arraylist, this way i can't use List (or i miss understood you...)

Comment: I saw your comments to Carlos, my thought about this is why not you convert your object as a JSON string and handle in the android app as JSON. This makes easier and you can less the overhead of serialization and deserialization. Its just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Hibernate Javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/collection/PersistentList.html) , PersistentList is also Serializable. Your POJO can have a reference to List, but in Runtime and instance of PersistentList -which is Serializable- should be used.

In a nutshell, just use List interface.

Comment: same the problem is that i  move Person object from Server to my Android and when my android app try to DeSerialize Person object i get null object because this List instead using Arraylist, this way i can't use List (or i miss understood you...)

Comment: Then the problem is Serialization. Hibernate entities maybe have been enhaced and serialization gets difficult (I have a similar problem with JDO). Have you tried DTO's? What mechanism are you using for serialization?

Comment: this my DeSerializa function: public static Object deserializeObject(byte[] b){                       ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(b)); 
        Object object = in.readObject(); 
        in.close(); return object;

Comment: i use the same function in the server side and in my android app side and when i run it  from the android it's return null... (if i put in server side before i send it the android side List temp=new ArrayList it's work fine...)